# Is it possible to create a roaming profile on Ubuntu to NAS

Tags: nas

I installed a ubuntu desktop and installed certain software's.Also i created multiple users.Is it possible to create /home of a user to a Netgear NAS.

Its just like create  a roaming profile on Netgear NAS.

Comment: Have you tried to install Samba as AD (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller) the Ubuntu system and add the controler to the NAS?

Comment: Roaming : the idea is to be able to load the same user profile from any workstation. It includes syncing. Is that what you need? Or you just need 1 Station and some users?

Comment: @cmak.fr   Actually i planned is to sync my /home replica to NAS drive.I tried editing  Fstab but notable to login... entry done on fstab ip::/Ubuntu_Hme /home/user1 nfs defaults

Comment: If you Nas is NFS capable, it will be easier and mainly more native-featured for Ubuntu Linux... But SMB share can be auto-mounted as /home too. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: See this too : https://serverfault.com/questions/186916/how-do-i-mount-home-as-a-samba-share